# How to update events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am attempting to setup my FullCalendar application to include event updating. I found this demo online that uses the eventClick callback to facilitate the updating of events. However, I don't fully understand how this demo works. why is the jsEvent parameter included if it is not actually used throughout the callback? Should this parameter be removed? Thanks!

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

```
select: function(start, end) {
  var title = prompt("Event Content:");
  var eventData;
  if (title) {
    eventData = {
      title: title,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      color: $("#colorPicker").val()
    };
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
  }
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
},

eventRender: function(event, element) {
  element
    .find(".fc-content")
    .prepend("<span class='closeBtn material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
  element.find(".closeBtn").on("click", function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
  });
},

eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
  var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", calEvent.title);
  calEvent.title = title;
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);

},
```

});
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update FullCalendar Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856344/how-to-update-fullcalendar-events)

Comment: please don't post the same question twice in succession. Thanks.