# How to update FullCalendar Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am attempting to set up a FullCalendar application that enables updates to newly-created calendar events. I found a demo on Codepen that uses the eventClick callback to facilitate this. However, I don't understand why the jsEvent parameter is included in the function header, when it doesn't look like it is actually used inside this callback. Is it necessary to write out jsEvent in:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {...}
```

or can jsEvent just be taken out? Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    select: function(start, end) {
      var title = prompt("Event Content:");
      var eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
      }
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element
        .find(".fc-content")
        .prepend("<span class='closeon material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
      element.find(".closeon").on("click", function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
      });
    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
      var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", calEvent.title);
      calEvent.title = title;
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `I don't understand why the jsEvent parameter is included` ...you can use it if you need it. It's not there for fun. It's not as useful as the event data, but people might want it for a specific purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

> `event` is an Event Object that holds the event’s information (date,
>   title, etc).
>
> `jsEvent` holds the jQuery event with low-level information such as
>   click coordinates.

If you don't need access to the jQuery event in your `eventClick`, you can remove it.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent) { ... }
```